# Returning and subscribing to the most recent value in a Firestore subcollection

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, combine

I'm trying to load or create a "Season" which is basically a quarter or a month long block of time stored as a subcollection document inside a user profile document in cloud Firestore.

I have an "order" field in the Season subcollection that increments with each newly created season, and my query is just finding the most recent one.

I call this function (loadOrCreateCurrentSeason) that loads the most recent season, which returns a Combine Future - either a Season in my data model or an error, and it subscribes to that. It will return the season it finds as long as there is no error, and as long as the season it returns encompasses the current date.

If either of those are not true, it will create a new one and add that document to Firebase.

The issue I'm having is that in the helper function I'm using to return the most recent season, when it loads the document and tries to convert it to my app's model for Seasons (`let x = try document.data(as: Season.self`) my app keeps returning x as nil.

I'm not sure if this is an error with my query, or how I have the function set up to return the data as a Season, but I'm wondering if there's anything in there that may be preventing the app from converting the Firestore document into a Season?

Main function called on initialization of the Repository:

```
    func loadOrCreateCurrentSeason() {
        var _ = loadMostRecentSeason()
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { error in
                self.addSeasonToSubcollection(season: Season(lastOrder: 0))
            }, receiveValue: { [weak self] season in
                    if season.endDate < Date() {
                        let oldOrder = season.order
                        self?.saveCurrentSeasonToPast()
                        self?.currentSeason = self?.createCurrentSeason(order: oldOrder)
                        self?.addSeasonToSubcollection(season: season)
                    } else {
                        self?.currentSeason = season
                    }
                })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

Helper Function called to specifically load the most recent season from Firebase:

```
    func loadMostRecentSeason() -> Future<Season, ErrorLoadingSeason> {
        let seasonRef = db.collection("users").document(userProfile.id!).collection("season")
        
        return Future<Season, ErrorLoadingSeason> { promise in
            seasonRef.order(by: "order", descending: true)
                .limit(to: 1)
                .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error getting most recent season: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                        promise(Result.failure(ErrorLoadingSeason.NoSeasonFound))
                    } else {
                        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                            do {
                                let x = try document.data(as: Season.self)
                                if x != nil {
                                    promise(Result.success(x!))
                                } else {
                                    promise(Result.failure(ErrorLoadingSeason.NoSeasonFound))
                                }
                            } catch {
                                print("An error converting the most recent season")
                                print(error)
                                promise(Result.failure(ErrorLoadingSeason.couldNotConvertData))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Here's my structure for Seasons if this makes a difference:

```
struct Season: Codable, Identifiable {
    
    // Identifiers
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var title: String?
    var userId: String
    var order: Int
    
    //Completion Details
    var startDate: Date
    var endDate: Date
    // var seasonType: SeasonType?
    
    init(lastOrder: Int) {
        let userProfile = CurrentUserProfile.shared.currentUser!
        
        self.userId = userProfile.id!
        self.startDate = Date().startOfPeriod(userProfile.seasonLength ?? .quarter)
        self.endDate = Date().endOfPeriod(userProfile.seasonLength ?? .quarter)
        self.order = lastOrder + 1
        self.title = setTitle(userProfile: userProfile)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm if the information that's being retrieved from Firestore is correct? You mentioned that the issue happens when you try to convert it to your app's model, so this exactly what the issue is?

Comment: Yeah it is - I added a line in there to print x after it gets set, and it appears x is not actually nil, but is set to something. I thought it wasn't, but I think I had a breakpoint on the wrong line. I think I figured out the solution, and it has to do with my receiveCompletion. I'll post below. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue had to do with how I was receiving the completion within the .sink method.

Previously I had it set to:

```
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { error in
                self.addSeasonToSubcollection(season: Season(lastOrder: 0))
            }, receiveValue: ...
```

I had thought that because it wasn't hitting the `receiveValue:` block, x must not have been set, but it appears I needed to have different handling for failure with an error vs successful completion (seems like a very basic error).

Adding a switch statement to break if it finished successfully, seems to have fixed the issue:

```
    func loadOrCreateCurrentSeason() {
        var _ = loadMostRecentSeason()
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    self.addSeasonToSubcollection(season: Season(lastOrder: 0))
                }
            }, receiveValue: { [weak self] season in
                    if season.endDate < Date() {
                        let oldOrder = season.order
                        self?.currentSeason = self?.createCurrentSeason(order: oldOrder)
                        self?.addSeasonToSubcollection(season: Season(lastOrder: oldOrder))
                    } else {
                        self?.currentSeason = season
                    }
                })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```